# Powermock (With Easymock) no last call on a mock available

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock, powermock

I am trying to just run a simple test case.  I have the following method.

```
public static void run(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    CommandLineArguments opts = CommandLineOptionProcessor.getOpts(args);
}
```

I will continue to build this method / test case as I go.  However I just wanted to make sure a simple test case worked first.  So I wrote the following test.

```
@Test
public void testRun() {
    String[] args = {"--arg1", "value", "--arg2", "value2"};

    mockStatic(CommandLineOptionProcessor.class);
    expect(CommandLineOptionProcessor.getOpts(args));

    EasyMock.replay(CommandLineOptionProcessor.class);
}
```

After that I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available
```

I read some of the other posts on StackOverflow but their solution seemed to be that they were using PowerMock with Mockito.   I am using Powermock and Easymock, so that should not be the problem.

I followed Rene's advice and added the following to the top of my class.

```
@PrepareForTest(CommandLineOptionProcessor.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class DataAssemblerTest {
```

I fixed the previous error.  But now I have this error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a mock: java.lang.Class
at org.easymock.internal.ClassExtensionHelper.getControl(ClassExtensionHelper.java:61)
at org.easymock.EasyMock.getControl(EasyMock.java:2172)
at org.easymock.EasyMock.replay(EasyMock.java:2074)
.
.
.
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this would be great.

Comment: No. I am currently not using Maven.

Comment: @RenéLink I fixed the issue with JavaAssist.  Turns out I just didn't have the Library in the project.  So that is fine now.  However, I now have this new issue that says 'Not a mock'.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Did you annotate the test class with `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and `@PrepareForTest(CommandLineOptionProcessor.class)`?

```
 @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
 @PrepareForTest(CommandLineOptionProcessor.class)
 public class TestClass {

     @Test
     public void testRun(){
```

You need the `@PrepareForTest(CommandLineOptionProcessor.class)` at the test class level. See the [Powermock doc](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic):

> Use the @PrepareForTest(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class) annotation at the class-level of the test case.

Also ensure that the required libraries are on the test classpath.

In your case the [javassist](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/javassist/javassist/3.16.1-GA/javassist-3.16.1-GA.jar) library is missing. Put it on the classpath. Maybe some other libs are also missing... we will see.

If you get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a mock: java.lang.Class
```

then you are using `EasyMock.replay()`, but you must use `PowerMock.replay()`

Comment: Oh okay.  I had tried @PrepareForTest but I had done it at the method-level.  When I had @PrepareForTest(CommandLineOptionProcessor.class) and @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) to the Class Level I now get a new error.  I will edit my Original Post with the error.

Comment: Yeah I just found that as well.  I had to make one more change to my test (but that was just my test failing).  It works great now.  Thanks for all the help and the walkthrough of Mocking a static method w/ Powermock.

Def. a bit confusing when you're new to it.

Answer (score -1):

```
 EasyMock.expectLastCall()
```

or

```
 EasyMock.expectLastCall().anyTimes()
```

or

```
 EasyMock.expectLastCall().andAnswer(..)
```

is not present in your code, must be after the method you want to test
this is in case your test method is a void method.

otherwise you can use :

```
expect(CommandLineOptionProcessor.getOpts(args)).andReturn(object);
```

also please add this to you test class :

```
  @ObjectFactory
public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {

    return new org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory( );
}
```

Comment: What does adding that to the test class do?

Comment: I had an issue - an exception when tried to mock static classes and this helped me.